# How to import a file with 3 columns of numerical data and visualize it with ListPointPlot3D?

Tags: graphics3d, numerics, import, data

The file is plain ascii. e.g. 100 rows, each row like "1.23  2.34 3.45".

I'm a complete novice with Mathematica, I assume this will be trivial.

Answer (score 1):

Try using

```
Import["/PATH/file.txt", "Table"];
```

This will convert each data point into a 2-D list. From, there you can easily plot any column with respect to any column. I don't know what is your data, but I am assuming them to be all numbers.

Comment: This works perfectly! Thank you.

Comment: Yes, thank you, this worked perfectly! My data is all numeric, in 3 columns.
When I then passed the Import[ ] expression to ListPointPlot3D[] the data displayed in a 3D box as I needed!  Well, nearly. The box & data are displayed with normal perspective, but for our purposes we need to see and rotate it without perspective.